# Passing php variable to onclick function

Tags: javascript, php

Below code not working.How to echo php variable to use for redirection.

```
<input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = "addMedia.php?pro=<?php echo $pId; ?>">
```

Comment: This should. What does `var_dump($pId)` output?

Comment: `onclick="window.location = "` You need to escape your quotes or use single quotes.

Comment: Your quotes are causing you trouble. Use single quotes inside the double ones: `onclick="window.location='addMedia.php?pro=<?php echo $pId; ?>'"`

Comment: Can u plzz type the corrected code plzz.

Comment: @AnkitaSansarwal please mark and up-vote the answer, it will help others.thanks.

Comment: No response from the OP's even after asking. frustrating, deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with your PHP, but the javascript isn't quite right...

```
<input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = "addMedia.php?pro=<?php echo $pId; ?>">
```

Will echo:

```
 <input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = "addMedia.php?pro=value_of_pId">
```

Where there are mismatched open quotes.

So you need to have the JavaScript code in the double quotes, and not terminate these quotes accidentally:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = 'addMedia.php?pro=value_of_pId'">
```

So achieve this, your PHP looks like:

```
<input type="button" value="Add Media" onclick="window.location = 'addMedia.php?pro=<?php echo $pId; ?>'">
```